# In the context of the multi-armed bandit problem, how to make each decision output multiple discrete actions of different types?

Tags: database, reinforcement-learning, bayesian

I have many knobs with dicrete action space (for example: color in [red, green, black] and temperature in [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]). At each decision-making time, I want the multi-armed bandit to output two discrete actions, i.e., color and question. What should I do?

I expect a blog and code repository